# How to make a shader that shows the direction of the normals relative to another object?

Tags: shaders, normals, normal-map

We need a shader so that normals that look towards a third-party object color the mesh in white or its gradation.

[image]

Comment: subtract from empty position your current position (Texture Coordinate: Object). Normalize if you want the normal normalized. That's it.

Answer (score -1):

Not sure it would be 100% correct,
but looks like the [layer weight node](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/shader_nodes/input/layer_weight.html) would be what you need.

If you need an object's normals other than the camera to "track point" to another object, you should use an [attribute node](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/shader_nodes/input/attribute.html) and [that formula](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2571160/calculate-direction-angle-from-two-vectors) to match it.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hi, thanks for the post. This site is not a regular forum, answers should be substantial, stand on their own, and thoroughly explain the solution and required steps. One liners and short tips rarely make for a good answer. If you can, [edit] your post and provide some more details about the procedure and how it works, perhaps add a few [images](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963) illustrating some steps and final result. See [How to write a good answer?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer), otherwise it may be converted to a comment.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).